# What is the equivalent of .WORD in LC3?

Tags: assembly, lc3

```
; Define memory locations for user input buffer and opcode output
INPUT_BUFFER .WORD x2000 ; Memory location to store user input
OPCODE_OUTPUT .WORD x2004 ; Memory location to store opcode output
```

I tried = . and =. they didn't work unfortunately

Comment: My understanding is that LC3 is implemented thru an emulator.  This means that the instructions available would depend on which emulator you're using, and you don't specify.  Google found me [these docs](https://people.cs.georgetown.edu/~squier/Teaching/HardwareFundamentals/LC3-trunk/docs/LC3-AssemblyManualAndExamples.pdf).  If this is what you are using, I'd expect something like `INPUT_BUFFER .BLKW 1`.

Comment: `= .` looks like part of `foo = .` in GAS syntax to define a symbol whose value is the current position, the same as using `foo:` (a label) to define a symbol with the same value (address).  Is that what you're trying to do?  `.word` in GAS emits a word of data to the output, totally different from defining an assemble-time constant or label.  What are you actually trying to do?  Set absolute addresses for where some buffers are located?  In some assemblers, `org` sets the current position, so you'd do that before stuff you wanted at a specific place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `.FILL ...` to provide a value for an initialized data word as `.word ...` would work in other assembly languages.

```
INPUT_BUFFER .FILL x2000
OPCODE_OUTPUT .FILL x2004
```

---

Use `.BLKW ...` to provide a count of a number of zero initialized data words.

---

There is no `equ` or `equate` or `#define` or `=` to declare numeric constants as far as I know.

But `.word` doesn't declare a constant either, it declares an initialized data word, which is exactly what `.fill` does.  (There is a difference in that that `.word ...` usually accepts  multiple comma separated values, whereas LC-3's `.fill ...` requires one argument per line.)

---

You can use these labels with LC-3's indirect loads and stores, `LDI` and `STI`.  For example,

```
LDI R0, INPUT_BUFFER
```

will use the data memory location at `INPUT_BUFFER` to get the address of where to go to get the value to put into `R0`.  So, the instruction itself refers to `INPUT_BUFFER`, and `INPUT_BUFFER` stores x2000, which is the effective address used to fetch from memory for `R0`.

You can also load the pointer value directly:

```
LD R1, INPUT_BUFFER    # now have x2000 in R1
LDR R0, R1, #0         # load from location at R1+#0, so x2000
```

And further, you can increment/modify the memory location at `INPUT_BUFFER`, so

```
LD R1, INPUT_BUFFER
ADD R1, R1, #1
ST R1, INPUT_BUFFER
```

That will change the memory location at `INPUT_BUFFER` to x2001 (assuming it was x2000 to start with), so for example, a next `LDI` or `STI` to that memory location will ultimately address memory location x2001.

---

Personally for small algorithms I would prefer to load pointers into registers and use them there including incrementing in registers in loops for example.  LC-3, with 8 usable registers, is register rich compared to MARIE, HACK, LMC and some others.